# very low file transfer speed between two wireless computers over local network

Tags: networking, mate, transfer

I bought a  new laptop and installed Ubuntu 22.04 Mate Desktop. My other old laptop has Ubuntu 20.04 Mate Desktop.
I want to transfer files from old comp to new one. I tried various tools to move files:

**1**

```
  scp -r  kenn@192.168.1.104:/home/kenn /home
```

**2**
on the first computer:

```
  tar -cz . | nc -q 10 -l -p 45453
```

on the second computer:

```
  nc -w 10 192.168.1.107 45453 | tar -xz
```

**3**
on the first computer:

```
 python3 -m http.server 45454
```

on the second computer:

```
 wget -r 192.168.1.114:45454/.
```

**4**

Teamviwer file transfer

But, none of them exceeds 400KB, transfer speed incredibly slow around 350KB.

Samba file sharing is not working.

While my current internet speed 33000 Mbit for both computer, why is local data transfer so slow?

Comment: The internet speed is of no concern the way you describe the problem.

Comment: What I am recommending is not a solution to the problem but an alternative. If possible (both computers have ethernet ports and you can wait for a couple days) you can buy/make a crossover ethernet cable and connect both computers with a 100M or 1000M crossover ethernet cable. Or a buy directly a suitable storage (SATA or NVMe)to USB adapter to eliminate the second computer from the equation.

Answer (score 0):

With what you have told us there is no simple answer. Certainly scp should be your best option. If that's slow, then everything will be slow.

Have you check both computers to make sure that they are not doing any other network traffic?

How loaded is your router / hub? If this is a low cost hub it could be bandwidth limited. If anything else is running on it, this will slow down connectivity.

The old methods also work: you can copy the data on to a USB and move that between the PCs.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: There is not much bandwidth usage on the modem.